# Logback extended ClassicConverter class returns %PARSER_ERROR[NameConvertor]

Tags: java, logback

i try to make simple extended ClassicConverter which looks like this :

```
package com.test;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

public class NameConverter extends ClassicConverter {
    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {

        return "This is NameConverter";
    }
}
```

And the logback file :

```
<included>

     <conversionRule conversionWord="NameConvertor"
                    converterClass="com.test.PackageNameConverter" />

    <property name="cPattern"
                      value="%d{HH:mm:ss}  [%thread] %logger{35}  |%NameConverter %msg%n" />

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <pattern>${cPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>
</included>
```

But i keep getting :

```
19:08:01  [Thread-12] DEBUG  |%PARSER_ERROR[NameConvertor]|  testtest
```

Comment: The error probably indicates the typo in your config XML: `conversionWord=NameConvertor"` (missing open quote)

Comment: Sorry this was my copy mistake i fixed it it do have : Apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="NameConvertor"
                    converterClass="com.test.PackageNameConverter" />
to 
   <conversionRule conversionWord="NameConvertor"
                    converterClass="com.test.NameConverter" />
```